# Search with grep SQL numeric data types

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I'm trying to do a grep to list all files in a directory containing a specific string variation on a linux system.  The files are DDLs for stored procedures and I'm looking for all files that have a NUMERIC or DECIMAL declaration with a precision of 2 (i.e.  DECIMAL(x,2) or NUMERIC(x,2)).  Case insensitive, and Whitespace is to be ignored.

Examples:

```
DECIMAL(13,2)
DECIMAL(13, 2)
DECIMAL( 13, 2 )
Decimal(13 , 2)
DECIMAL     ( 13, 2    )
NUMERIC(13         , 2)
numeric ( 13 , 2)
NUMERIC(8,2      )
CAST(INT (PURCHASE_DATE ) AS NUMERIC(8,0)) AS BUYDATE;
```

What I've come up with thus far is:

```
grep --include='*.DDL' -inP 'sproc' -e '.*Numeric|Decimal *\( *[0-9] *\, *2 *\).*'
```

But of course, its not working and I'm simply missing the reason why.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What isn't working?  Are you seeing no output, or just not the output you expect?  Is there an error?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `-P`, you should use caracter classes, or scapes, for each space

```
grep --include='*.DDL' -inP -e '.*Numeric|Decimal[ ]*\([ ]*[0-9][ ]*\,[ ]*2[ ]*\).*'
```

or

```
grep --include='*.DDL' -inP -e '.*Numeric|Decimal\s*\(\s*[0-9]\s*\,\s*2\s*\).*'
```

or even:

```
grep --include='*.DDL' -inP -e '.*Numeric|Decimal\ *\(\ *[0-9]\ *\,\ *2\ *\).*'
```

I personally prefer the first one, it seems clearer to me.

Just to make it clear, the `-i` will make the search case insensitive too.

Comment: What does `'sproc'` do?

Comment: None I think, it's a mistake, I will remove it

Answer (score 0):

I would perform the search like this:

```
grep --include='*.DDL' -inRP 'REGEX' *
```

With this REGEX:

```
(([Dd][Ee][Cc][Ii][Mm][Aa][Ll])|([Nn][Uu][Mm][Ee][Rr][Ii][Cc]))\s*\(\s*\d+\s*,\s*\d{1,2}\s*\)
```

Will match your examples, and:

> nUmErIc  (  1, 3  )
>
> DeCiMaL ( 2, 12)

Won't match:

> DeCiMaL ( 1, 123)
>
> DeCiMaL ( 2, 1 2)

You don't need the `-e` flag if you are already using `-P`. Also, you need to specify the path where you want to search, I used `*`, and added the `-R` flag in case there are sub folders.

Comment: With the -i flag you can just say `numeric` instead of `[Nn][Uu][Mm][Ee][Rr][Ii][Cc]`